# How to convert polars dataframe column type from float64 to int64?

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

I have a polars dataframe, like:

```
import polars as pl
df = pl.DataFrame({"foo": [1.0, 2.0, 3.0], "bar": [11, 5, 8]})
```

How do I convert the first column to int64 type?
I was trying something like:

```
df.select(pl.col('foo')) = df.select(pl.col('foo')).cast(pl.Int64)
```

but it is not working.
In Pandas it was super easy:

```
df['foo'] = df['foo'].astype('int64')
```

Thanks.

Comment: did you try `df.cast(pl.Int64, strict=False)` ?

Comment: Then I get the error: AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'cast'

Comment: df.with_column(pl.col('foo').cast(pl.Int64, strict=False)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Select your [`col`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.col.html), [`cast`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/series/api/polars.Series.cast.html) it to (`int64`) and add it back to the original *DataFrame* [`with_columns`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.with_columns.html).

```
df = df.with_columns(pl.col("foo").cast(pl.Int64))
```

Output :

```
print(df)

shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬─────┐
│ foo ┆ bar │
│ --- ┆ --- │
│ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════╪═════╡
│ 1   ┆ 11  │
│ 2   ┆ 5   │
│ 3   ┆ 8   │
└─────┴─────┘
```